# SetValue on Linq2Sql Object

Tags: c#, sql, reflection, setvalue

Is it possible to use reflection or expressions to modify a Linq2Sql object?
As a simple example that will not work:

```
MyDataClassDataContext db = new MyDataClassDataContext();
var actionData = (from ac in db.Actions where ac.ActionID == action.ActionID select ac).First();
var property = typeof(Action).GetProperty("ActionID");
property.SetValue(33, actionData);

...

db.SubmitChanges();
db.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but you must call the Update method explicitly, not only SubmitChanges() since linq2db does not track changes

Comment: Apologies, I should have written that it fails on the `SetValue`. It says that `33` is not the same type. This is just an example, but in this example, both `33` and `ActionID` are both int (Both non-nullable), and `actionData.ActionID = 33;` works fine